# How to use glob function in remote directory

Tags: php, glob

I'm trying to use the glob function in PHP to output certain types of files that are in a remote directory on my web page, but when I run my code, I get no output.

```
<?php
print_r(glob("/path/to/remote/dir/*.txt"));
?>
```

Comment: I think a quick squint at the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and the first NOTE in the NOTES section will answer this for you.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, is there another function I can use that will give me the same result?

Comment: I'm not sure that `remote files` are the issue here as the path does not begin with `http(s)` so it is a `local` file relative to the webserver is it not? The directory is ON the webserver? The lack of closing `"` for the path might be an issue though - of use the fully qualified path rather than the relative one here